# Windows Phone integration with social networks

Tags: c#, facebook, rest, windows-phone-8, twitter

I'm writing simple application for Windows Phone 8, and I want to implement sharing in socials (Twitter and Facebook). But there is a problem: third-party libraries don't work with Portable Class library for Windows Phone. But if I use REST API, I need to interact with the `WebBrowser` element. Is there a way to authorize and post messages without `WebBrowser`?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394009%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It is not quite clear what you mean exactly but to share a status on Facebook or Twitter you can use the `ShareStatusTask`

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;

ShareStatusTask shareStatusTask = new ShareStatusTask();
shareStatusTask.Status = "I'm developing a Windows Phone application!";
shareStatusTask.Show();
```

Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394027(v=vs.105).aspx)